# How to implement a restaurant order from a restaurant menu using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I've made an app that displays a menu of a restaurant (in a tableview). What I want to do is let users add items to an order and (text or email) it to the restaurant.

I am just not sure what approach to use. Should I create an array when they click a row in the table? and then send that array as sms? or is there another way to achieve this?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's a little vague.  You might have to use a service that the restaurant already provides.  Maybe even make an HTTP request.

Comment: Actually, my problem is not actually sending the order to the restaurant. Like you said, I can achieve it with http request. I need advice on how to prepare the order in the app. Sending it is the easy bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the question is, but here is some points I would consider:

1. I would use web services using POST. In your case, you probably need two: one for getting menus and the other one for submitting orders.
2. I would use objects no matter whether it is JSON, XML or others of the information. In your app side, you can create a class, say order, contains two fields, Item Id and Item count. So when submitting your order, the web service would be very easy, you only need to pass a NSArray of your order objects.

I have an app similar to yours, I used SOAP based web services on our .Net server side. I guess for JSON it shouldn't be that much different.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are [presumably] already maintaining an array that supports the UITableView.

When the time comes to submit the order, a commonly used approach would be to convert the array to JSON, and submit it to the server as via a HTTP PUT or POST.

iOS has inbuilt support for JSON from iOS 5 onwards.

...of course, the web server at the other end needs to be expecting the HTTP request.

Comment: The array comes from the website. it is json data. The menu that is. But the whole data will not be sent to the restaurant. Only the ones user selects will be sent to the restaurant as an order. I also want to show the user what he is ordering before s/he sends it, along with the cost of the order.

Comment: OK, then just select the subset from the menu that the user chooses, and maintain that as an array, and then return that back as JSON when the order is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create an app for a menu so a waiter could  take order on phone then direct it to the kitchen to be recieved  then the food prepared without the waiter having to physically take a piece of paper to the kitchen

Comment: Yes, if the kitchen has a computer with internet connection

Comment: I don't think that's the point of the original question. The app is meant for normal customers send order through an app. For the restaurant, I don't think they will worry about the phone app to replace a piece of paper that a waiter suppose to write the order on. Actually there could be a good system for the kitchen that when the order is received from a customer, it can pop up on a computer screen in the kitchen. In that case, it's all about how the server side code should handle the order after they came in.